# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in swapping of two number in c

Tags: c

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int *tmp;
    *tmp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*tmp;
}

void main()
{
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("Enter another number\n");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    printf("Numbers before swap\n");
    printf("value of i : %d\n",i);
    printf("value of j : %d\n",j);
    swap(&i,&j);
    printf("Numbers after swap\n");
    printf("value of i : %d\n",i);
    printf("value of j : %d\n",j);
}
```

Above one is my code and it is working fine but when the output prints on console it will give Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Here is the o/p

```
abc:~/Desktop/C$ ./a.out

Enter any number

34

Enter another number

54

Numbers before swap

value of i : 34

value of j : 54

Numbers after swap

value of i : 54

value of j : 34

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: i tried like this int main() and at the end return 0 but facing still same issue

Comment: `tmp` is not pointing to a valid memory location.

Comment: you would have easily found that yourself if you added a suitable warning level to your compiler invocation. Accustom yourself to that and life will be a lot easier.

Comment: Mfro please can you tell me, how we can add warning level to compiler invocation ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `tmp` (which you declared as pointer) uninitialized.

try

```
int tmp;
tmp=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=tmp;
```

Answer (score 5):

Why are u creating pointer variable to store the value

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int *tmp;
    *tmp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*tmp;
}
```

Instead use a simple variable like this :

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int tmp;
    tmp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=tmp;
}
```

always use return type of **main()** to be **int** and put **return 0;** at last